# Undefined reference in clang when linking to a library compiled with GCC5

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, abi, gcc5

I try to use the ubuntu 15.10 repository version of libmuparser (package libmuparser2v5). Compiling with gcc works fine, but not with clang. I dug deeper into this to come up with the following minimal (not) working example and a few questions.

Consider a library with a simple class that takes a `string` and returns a `string`.

`testlib.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

struct Test {
    std::string str;

    void set(std::string s);
    std::string get();
};
```

`testlib.cpp`:

```
#include "testlib.h"

void Test::set(std::string s) {
    str = s;
}

std::string Test::get() {
    return str;
}
```

This is compiled with gcc 5.2.1 as static library with

```
g++ -Wall -c testlib.cpp -o testlib-gcc.o
ar rcs libtest-gcc.a testlib-gcc.o
```

Now compiling an application `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testlib.h"

int main()
{
    Test p;
    p.set("Hello!");
    std::cout << p.get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with clang 3.6.2-1 by using

```
clang++ main.cpp -o out-clang libtest-gcc.a
```

results in the error

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `Test::get()'
```

Now I found out that gcc5 has a new feature, called ABI tags, to help versioning libraries and prevent linking, when it is not compatible. Looking at the static library

```
$ nm -gC libtest-gcc.a
```

gives:

```
testlib-gcc.o:
0000000000000026 T Test::get[abi:cxx11]()
0000000000000000 T Test::set(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
```

So the ABI tag `cxx11` has been added for `get` but not for `set`. The tag is apparently added, when a method returns a `string`. That is why clang claims only about not finding `Test::get()`.

I guess this is done to give `get` a calling signature that makes clear that c++11 is required to link with that function. For `set` this is not necessary, due to the `__cxx11` in the type.

Questions:

- Am I right with my guess or is there maybe something more to be added?
- If so, how to fix this?

  - What can a **library writer** do to make a library linkable to both gcc 5.2 and clang 3.6 compiled code? (**Source code changes?**)
  - What can a **library user** do to compile and link with clang 3.6 against a library compiled with gcc 5.2 or vice versa. (**Source code changes or compilation flags?**)
  - What can a **package maintainer** do to make a library linkable to both gcc 5.2 and clang 3.6 compiled code? (**Compilation flags?**)
  - Will this be fixed by the **clang developers** in future version (which version)? (**ABI compatibility by default?**) However it would still be nice to have a solution now, since otherwise clang is hard to use on ubuntu 15.10 and derivatives.

Additional information:

- The signature of `get` is defined when `testlib.cpp` is compiled. Thus a shared object would not make any difference. One can also use `nm -gC testlib-gcc.o` to see the symbols.
- In a library compiled with clang the signature of `get` is `Test::get()`. Then gcc cannot find the symbol `Test::get[abi:cxx11]()`, so the compatibility is mutually broken.
- Using the compile flag `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` for gcc (found [here](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/)) is no solution, since then the signature of set is also changed: `Test::set(std::string)` (but `get` is fine then).
- Using the compile flag `-stdlib=libc++` in clang does not seem to help, since it also reports the undefined reference to `Test::get()` (and a lot more undefined references).

Comment: When you use `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`, you need to use it with the program you compile with Clang too, if it uses the GCC standard library (libstdc++). The `std::__cxx11` is a private GCC standard library-only namespace, if I [read this right](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, compiling both library and application with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` helps. However, my actual use case here is a library in the repository, that is compiled with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1`. It seems not to be possible to use the abi_tag ("cxx11") attribute in clang. So is it simply not possible maybe?

Comment: In that case it's not possible, unless there's a fix in the clang source repositories and you build clang from source. Oh, there *is* an [issue in the clang issue tracker for this](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23529), but it doesn't seem to be merged into trunk yet.

Comment: Compatibility of libraries/objects compiled with different C++ compilers is a nightmare since C++11 and the recommendation is not to rely on it. Having said that, the problem is mostly limited to `std::string` (and related classes such as `std::stringstream`) and if you can avoid using any library functionality using `string`s (which may include catching exceptions by type), you may be okay (that's my experience).