# Trying to reference an overloaded method with const in C++ using clang

Tags: c++, clang, overloading, clang++

In clang there is [this file](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Type_8h_source.html). I'm trying to reference one of the overloaded methods:

```
00909   std::string getAsString(const PrintingPolicy &Policy) const;
```

**I tried:**

```
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (&p2)(const clang::PrintingPolicy&) = &clang::QualType::getAsString;
```

**and got:**

```
REPL:1:73: error: address of overloaded function 'getAsString' does not match required type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (const clang::PrintingPolicy &)'
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (&p2)(const clang::PrintingPolicy&) = &clang::QualType::getAsString
```

```
/home/a/julia/usr/bin/../include/clang/AST/Type.h:905:15: note: candidate function has different qualifiers **(expected none but found const)**
  std::string getAsString(const PrintingPolicy &Policy) const;
```

**I also tried:**

```
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (&p1)(clang::PrintingPolicy&) = &clang::QualType::getAsString;
```

**and got:**

```
candidate function has type mismatch at 1st parameter **(expected 'clang::PrintingPolicy &' but has 'const clang::PrintingPolicy &')**
```

Am I doing something wrong or is the compiler broken?

Comment: My money is definitely on you being wrong. (Hint: non-static member functions are very different from free functions.)

Comment: I just need the address of the method, and it seems like the compiler is ok with it until it shows the const?

Comment: Btw I'm doing this because of an open bug in clang similar to these poor chaps https://www.bountysource.com/issues/29193004-link-errors-on-debian-sid but their solution did not work for me

Comment: This is also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368237/undefined-reference-in-clang-when-linking-to-a-library-compiled-with-gcc5 :/